# facing issue to select radio button in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on form which have combination of input field and radio button. Whenever I select the radio button, it is not getting selected but value is getting update in form state . For some reason, radio button is not showing selected

```
const InputForm = () => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({name: "", job: "no" });
    const {name, job} = form;
    
 const handleJob = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    setForm({ ...form, job: value });
  };

const onInputChange = (e) => {
setForm({...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}


return (
<>
                 <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control input-text-box"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={onInputChange}
                />
<div className="form-check-inline mx-2">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="form-check-input"
                    name="radioOption"
                    value="yes"
                    onChange={handleJob}
                    checked={job === "yes"}
                    
                  />{" "}
                  <label className="form-check-label" for="radioOption">
                    Yes&nbsp;
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="radioOption"
                    className="form-check-input"
                    value="no"
                    onChange={handleJob}
                    checked={job === "no"}
                     
                  />{" "}
                  <label className="form-check-label" for="radioOption">
                    No
                  </label>
                </div>
</>
);
};

export default InputForm;
```

Comment: Your code does not run. `Uncaught ReferenceError: onChangeInput is not defined`

Comment: Yeah as @CertainPerformance suggested you need to either change the function name or the function name you are passing in onChange event.

Comment: This Code seems to work perfectly fine. refer to https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-drake-c9qpb7?file=/src/InputForm.js

Comment: I don't see any thing not working fine. Just pasted your code  in codesandbox with a few changes to get rid of errors:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-violet-cw2hvv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Update the code with onInputChange

Comment: It's working but when i click on yes it's not showing as selected, however state getting updated